# input binding is not firing command wpf wvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

i have this in MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="Delete"  Command="{Binding DelAllMessages}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
```

and in MainViewModel

```
public void DelAllMessages()
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(
                "Are you sure you want to delete?",
                                          "Confirmation",
                                          MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                                          MessageBoxImage.Question);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                // todo
            }
        }
}
```

when i press ctrl+del in keyboard in window then this method does not hit.what is missing?

Comment: Commands arent just functions, they're commands. [Overview of commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview) and [Custom command example](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Input%20and%20Commands/CustomRoutedCommand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Commands instead of directly binding the method. One think to keep in mind is in order to have a communication between View model and View is via Properties.

**Step 1:-**

Create a Command Handler class and Implement `ICommand` as shown in the below code.

```
   public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _action;
    private bool _canExeute;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private bool canExeute
    {
        set
        {
            _canExeute = value;
            CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }


    public CommandHandler(Action<object> action, bool canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExeute = canExecute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExeute;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action(parameter);
    }
}
```

**Step 2:-**
Use the newly created class of Command in your Window's code behind.

Create a property of `ICommand` and provide your DelAllMessages() as your action to that Command, so when there is `Clt + Del` Pressed, it calls your method.

```
    private ICommand _KeyCommand;
    public ICommand KeyCommand
    {
        get { return _KeyCommand ?? (_KeyCommand = new CommandHandler(obj => DelAllMessages(), true)); }
    }
```

**Step 3:-**

Assign your your window class as `DataContext` to the windows' Xaml.

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Check out whole class Code.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private ICommand _KeyCommand;
    public ICommand KeyCommand
    {
        get { return _KeyCommand ?? (_KeyCommand = new CommandHandler(obj => DelAllMessages(), true)); }
    }


    public void DelAllMessages()
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(
            "Are you sure you want to delete?",
            "Confirmation",
            MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
            MessageBoxImage.Question);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            // todo
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4:-**

Bind the newly created Command property in Xaml.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="Delete"  Command="{Binding KeyCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Whole Xaml Code:-

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.TriggerTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="Delete"  Command="{Binding KeyCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```